# Spring Security 6 CustomAuthenticationFilter(intend to replace the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter) does not work

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security-oauth2

By reference https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-extra-login-fields

I intend to customize the the functionality of Spring security Authentication UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter to get the additional customized "loginForm" fields.

I created one customized filter

```
CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
```

and one customized authentication token

```
public class CustomAuthenticationToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
```

By using the below configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class AuthenticationSecurityConfig extends AbstractHttpConfigurer<AuthenticationSecurityConfig, HttpSecurity> {


@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);
    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(authenticationManager), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

@Bean
SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/css/**", "/login")
            .permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/resources/**")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin(form -> form
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
            )
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests(
                    auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .apply(securityConfig());
    return http.build();

}

}
```

I can successfully make the my AuthenticationProvider's

```
authenticate
```

method to be executed, and It can successfully return one "authenticated"

```
Authentication object.
```

However it will not redirect to the OAuth2 client's redirect page(I setup my project as one OIDC authorization server), it will stay at login page, the log will be like below:

.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://192.168.0.107:9000/oauth2/authorize?client_id=messaging-client&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.0.107%3A8080%2Fauth%2Fsigninwin%2Fmain&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20message.read&state=802af0dcd82a483eb726c1dffff0867d&code_challenge=t_tfBjZPRd228uEZuQJ56clfXokGYqiwkudQqKhWQqo&code_challenge_method=S256&prompt=login&response_mode=query&continue&continue to session
2022-11-30T19:48:05.063+08:00 DEBUG 63801 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://192.168.0.107:9000/login
2022-11-30T19:48:05.078+08:00 DEBUG 63801 --- [nio-9000-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2022-11-30T19:48:05.078+08:00 DEBUG 63801 --- [nio-9000-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2022-11-30T19:48:05.084+08:00 DEBUG 63801 --- [nio-9000-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext

If I will not use the customized filter CustomAuthenticationFilter, every thing will be fine(But of couse I can't get the additonal LoginForm fileds).

My build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "3.0.0-RC2"
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    id "java"
}
```

```
implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server:1.0.0"
```

Any ideas?

I suspected that the attributes of CustomAuthenticationFilter(use new to create the object) is not the same with attributes of the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter that spring security framework will initialize, need further check the disparity.

Comment: 3.0.0 is released

Comment: Yes, thanks, 3.0.0 was released at 11/24 2022, I switched to it, the issue still exist, I'm in the process to debug the code, currently I found some attributes for two filter is not the same, need investigate further

Comment: After debugging, I found the attributes for two AuthenticationFilter are not the same, the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter has been set with: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy [delegateStrategies = [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@74ec4df3, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfAuthenticationStrategy@4fe8ac61]], CustomAuthenticationFilter don't have this attribute set

Comment: Instead of use a customized/extended  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter , now only to customize the details source I figure things out 
.formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .authenticationDetailsSource(new JpaWebAuthenticationDetailsSource())
                        //.loginProcessingUrl("/dologin")
                        .permitAll()
                )

Answer (score 5):

There are two solutions,
the difference with previous versions is due to this change: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11110

*** First solution ***

You can use the old strategy (deprecated) with automatic saving of the SecurityContextHolder setting:

```
http.securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext.requireExplicitSave(false))
```

*** Second solution ***

Define an HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:

```
@Bean
public HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository() {
    return new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();
}
```

Set to http configuration:

```
http.securityContext().securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository())
```

finally set the context repository to your custom filter:

```
filter.setSecurityContextRepository(securityContextRepository());
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Unfortunately, when declaring the SecurityContextRepository Bean within the same Configuration class where the SecurityFilterChain lives you'll have to `@Lazy` inject the SecurityContextRepository into the custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter to avoid recursive calls on initialization. Since I'm still with SS5.8 and SB2.7.7 I can't say whether SB3.x will provide an accessible ContextBean by default or one will have to declare it anyway.

Comment: Thank you!  I was upgrading from spring security 5 to 6, and the authentication was happening, but spring wasn't allowing any authenticated requests through.  Your first solution `requireExplicitSave(false)` fixed it (it doesn't say it's deprecated, but maybe it is).

Answer (score 0):

[image: by add logging.level.org.apache.tomcat=DEBUG logging.level.org.apache.catalina=DEBUG in app properties]

My own custom JsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is located at 7th filter. The solution I think either you disabling csrf or setup csrf customizer

```
httpSecurity
   .csrf(customizer -> customizer.disable()) 
   ......
```