# Spring Boot 3 migration for JDBC session and Spring Security does not work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

This is a question for Spring Boot version 3.0.1.
This is working perfectly fine for version 2.7.5.

My app is using Spring Security and a JDBC session. So I get `X-Auth-Token` saved in `spring_session` table in my database (PostgreSQL). I have implemented the `UserDetailsService` interface to fetch the user from my DB when I call the login controller method.

When migrating to new Spring Boot 3 version, the major changes are happening in `WebSecurityConfig` class. Previously it was extending from the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class. So I know the problem is lying somewhere in this class.

Here I am copy and pasting my old version 2.7.5 (that works fine) and new 3.0.1 version of the `WebSecurityConfig` class:

### Spring Boot Version 2.7.5

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {        
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
            .cors()
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/usermanager/auth/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/usermanager/image/org/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/invalidSession*").anonymous()              
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()              
                .permitAll()
                .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)               
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionFixation()
                .migrateSession()               
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .expiredUrl("/sessionExpired.html")
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web
            .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/docs/**", "/resources/**", "/static/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler myFailureHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionStrategy() {
        return HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("client")
                    .password(passwordEncoder.encode("Client@Venturi"))
                    .roles("USER");      
        var daoAC = new DaoAuthenticationConfigurer(userDetailsService);
        daoAC.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        auth.apply(daoAC);
    }
}
```

### Spring Boot Version 3.0.1

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http,
                                                       PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder)
            throws Exception {
        var daoAC = new DaoAuthenticationConfigurer(userDetailsService);
        daoAC.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

        var builder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        builder.apply(daoAC);
        return builder.build();    
    }

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            "/api/usermanager/auth/login"           
    };

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {       
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()              
                .and()
            .cors()
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        requests -> requests.
                        requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionFixation()
                .migrateSession()               
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .expiredUrl("/sessionExpired.html")
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,
                "/docs/**", "/resources/**", "/static/**"
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler myFailureHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionStrategy() {
        return HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionIdResolver() {
        return HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
}
```

When I call the above auth/login controller API, I get the session ID populated in the `spring_session` table. But the `principal_name` in that table is `null`. I hope you are aware that the `spring_session` table is the default table created by Spring Session to save the session information.

In 2.7.5 version, the `principal_name` will be saved (user login name). So in subsequent requests, I can get the user by passing the `x-auth-token` in the HTTP request header. So my problem is now the `principal_name` is always `null` in the `spring_session` table when I call the above controller API.

Can anyone see if I am doing anything wrong when converting the `WebSecurityConfig` class to Spring Boot version 3?

Comment: I don't use formLogin. I call my controller to login to my app. I just send a POST request with body

Comment: I tried with formLogin too. same result.  This is how I authenticate. It has no problem. I debugged and it authenticate properly.

Comment: var authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
        if (authenticationToken.isAuthenticated()) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            orgUserRoleDto.setXAuthToken(RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId());
            logger.debug("User login {} successful!", username);
        }

Comment: @dur I got the answer from Max. Check his answer. Worked perfectly :-)

Answer (score 5):

The difference with previous versions is due to this change: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11110

You can use the old strategy (deprecated) with automatic saving of the SecurityContextHolder setting:

```
http.securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext.requireExplicitSave(false))
```

Comment: That is a really good tip. It works perfectly now. I wonder why this is not documented any where. I am sure lot of people will have similar issues with this change. You are a hero :-)

Comment: Do you know why it is deprecated? What is the new way to do this?

Comment: On the new SecurityContextHolderFilter which it replaced the deprecated SecurityContextPersistenceFilter it is written: 
"This improves the efficiency and provides better flexibility by allowing different authentication mechanisms to choose individually if authentication should be persisted."

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/6.0.1/api/org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextHolderFilter.html

Comment: I wrote here a non deprecated solution with a custom filter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74629234/spring-security-6-customauthenticationfilterintend-to-replace-the-usernamepassw/75002996#75002996

Comment: I create another question related, If you can answer, it will be great https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75017794/spring-boot-3-multiple-security-filter-chains-doesnt-work