# Spring boot 3 multiple security filter chains doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-3, spring-session

I am using Spring Boot 3.0.1. In my WebSecurityConfig class, I want to filter 2 types of api urls.
So I have 2 SecurityFilterChains. This is what I want to achieve.

```
1.) Login api: This one, I want to permit this url and save the session id to the database using Spring Sessions.
2.) Other white apis: I want to permit some urls without any security/session checks
3.) Any other api calls need to have the x-auth-token
```

The following code has only 1 SecurityFilterChain and it works perfectly fine to satisfy all the above 1,2,3 points.
For 1, it will create the session id in the spring_session table with the login user as the principal_name.
For 2, it will also create another session id in spring_session table with "client" as the principal_name.
I do not want to create a session id for 2. I only want to create session id when I call the 1 (login api). So I believe that I have to write 2 Filter chains. First one only for login api and create session id, second one for all the white apis to go through with out security/session checks.
How do I write 2 security filter chains?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        var daoAC = new DaoAuthenticationConfigurer(userDetailsService);
        daoAC.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        var builder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        builder.apply(daoAC);
        return builder.build();
    }

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {           
            "/api/usermanager/auth/login",
            "/api/usermanager/auth/app-login",
            "/api/usermanager/auth/resetPassword",
            "/api/usermanager/auth/health",
            "/api/usermanager/back-office/login",
            "/actuator/**",
            "/get-user-names",
            "/get-users",
            "/get-user",
            "/api/usermanager/users/activate",
            "/actuator/**",
            "/health/**",
            "/api/usermanager/org",
            "/api/usermanager/org/*/theme",
            "/api/usermanager/image/org/*/all",
            "/api/usermanager/image/org/*/logo.png"
    };

    @Bean   
    public SecurityFilterChain loginFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and().securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext.requireExplicitSave(false))
                .cors()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .securityMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        requests -> requests.
                                requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                ).httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .sessionManagement(session ->  session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                        .sessionFixation()
                        .migrateSession()
                        .maximumSessions(1)
                        .expiredUrl("/sessionExpired.html")
                        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false));
        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,
                "/docs/**", "/resources/**", "/static/**", "/img/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler myFailureHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionStrategy() {
        return HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionIdResolver() {
        return HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out this section in the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity_instances).

Answer (score 1):

Create more SecurityFilterChain Bean and add @Order(1) and @Order(2) annotations.

Check the Spring docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-securityfilterchain

Comment: My question is basically how do I stop creating session ids (spring_session table)for all other other requests? I only want to create it for specific /login api call. I added another SecurityFilterChain with order 2. But then it will stop the authentication for other apis.