# How to properly set SecurityContextRepository for a custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter in Spring Security 6?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Since Spring Security 6.0 an explicit saving of the SecurityContextRepository is required:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration/servlet/session-management.html#_require_explicit_saving_of_securitycontextrepository

This means that if a custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is used, a SecurityContextRepository must be provided to being able to persist the SecurityContext, like this:

```
@Component
public class InternalUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @PostConstruct
    private void setup() {
        super.setSecurityContextRepository(
                new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
                        new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository(),
                        new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()));
    }
    //...
}
```

It seems to be sufficient to specify the SecurityContextRepository only once in the AuthenticationFilter, although @Max in the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75002996/13609359) sets the repository in the SecurityFilterChain as well.

I have tested both variants and it doesn't seem to matter if a SecurityContextRepository is specified in the FilterChain or not. It also doesn't seem to matter if we use one bean for both AuthenticationFilter and FilterChain or create new repositories for each like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain mvcFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(true)
                        .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/login/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())

                .addFilterAt(internalUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

                .securityContext(securityContext -> securityContext
                        .securityContextRepository(
                                new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
                                        new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository(),
                                        new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()
                                )))
                //...
    }
}
```

This would indicate that only the repository of the AuthenticationFilter is used and the repository of the FilterChain is ignored.

My assumption would therefore be that creating the SecurityContextRepository in the AuthenticationFilter would be sufficient.

### So my questions are:

1. Do I see that right?
2. Or should I rather define a bean?
3. And is there any reason to set this bean in the SecurityFilterChain as well?

Many thanks for any help for clarification

Comment: I have exact the same question. My current theory is that the security chain implicitly has its own instance, but since they work on the same session it works if you create and new instance and persist it with that. I will have a look into the source to clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SecurityContextRepository` used in the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`-derived filters like your `InternalUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and in the `SecurityFilterChain` are different ones.

Obviously the filer's `SecurityContextRepository` is used exclusively by the filter to save the security context after a successful authentication.
If you don't specify the repository explicitly, it will create and use a `RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository`.

The `SecurityContextRepository` that you pass to the security chain builder on the other hand is used in multiple places, like it's passed to `SessionManagementFilter` during its creation by `SessionManagementConfigurer`, to `LogoutFilter` by `LogoutConfigurer` etc.
If you don't specify the repository explicitly, `SessionManagementConfigurer` will create for those components either a `new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository()` if the session creation policy is stateless, or a `new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(httpSecurityRepository, new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository())` otherwise.

So those are independent extension points which you can use if required. Otherwise default `SecurityContextRepository` implementations will be used.

Defining a `SecurityContextRepository` bean just won't do anything as the components I mentioned are not looking up the app context for it.

Comment: Thank your for this explicit explanation. That makes things a lot more clear. Can I use the same instance of a `new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository` for both usecases or should I provide separate ones?