# How to access authenticated user details in spring security 6?

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security 6.2.1 and Spring MVC 6.1.0

I would like to access the username of currently logged in user,how can I access the user details from he SecurityContextHolder?
As of updating from spring security 5 to 6,when trying to authenticate a user by getting the authentication from the SecurityContextHolder a null is returned. This previously worked without issues when using spring security/MVC 5.

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    
    String name = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

    User user = authenticationDAO.getUser(name);

    if (user != null && encoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())) {
        List<String> roles = authenticationDAO.getRoles(user.getId());

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

        if (roles != null) {
            for (String role : roles) {
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
            }
        }

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, authorities);
    }

    return null;
}
```

At this point when I try to later access the username that should be stored, the authentication object is null.

```
public String getAuthenticatedUser() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (authentication == null || AnonymousAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication.getClass())) {
        return null;
    }

    return authentication.getName();
}
```

Comment: Once the SecurityContextHolder is set it will remain set for the current request.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a custom `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` in place you have to provide and set up the `SecurityContextRepository` explicitly. For more details see [Session Management Migrations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/session-management.html) and [How to properly set SecurityContextRepository for a custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter in Spring Security 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75115505)

Now, if that's your case declare a dedicated bean:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityContextRepository delegatingSecurityContextRepository() {
    return new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
            new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository(),
            new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository());
}
```

And then inject it into your UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter to set it up like this:

```java
@Component
public class CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository;
    private final AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;
    private final AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @PostConstruct
    private void setup() {

        /* Settings must match those in the login-form */
        super.setUsernameParameter("identifier");
        super.setPasswordParameter("password");
        super.setFilterProcessesUrl(AUTH_FORM_AUTHENTICATION_URL);

        super.setSecurityContextRepository(securityContextRepository);
        super.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
        super.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);

        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }

    public CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(
            @Qualifier("customProviderManager") AuthenticationManager customProviderManager,
            @Qualifier("delegatingSecurityContextRepository") SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository,
            @Qualifier("customAuthenticationFailureHandler") AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler,
            @Qualifier("customAuthenticationSuccessHandler") AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler) {

        this.securityContextRepository = securityContextRepository;
        this.authenticationFailureHandler = authenticationFailureHandler;
        this.authenticationSuccessHandler = authenticationSuccessHandler;

        super.setAuthenticationManager(customProviderManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (!request.getMethod().equals("POST"))
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());

        String identifier = super.obtainUsername(request);
        identifier = identifier != null ? identifier.trim() : "";
        String password = super.obtainPassword(request);
        password = password != null ? password : "";

        CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(identifier, password);

        super.setDetails(request, authRequest);
        return super.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }

}
```